# unittest - setting env variables before init method of file in package

Tags: go

I have the following layout in my project:

```
MyProject
├── config
│   └── config.go
│   └── config_test.go
│   └── testdata
│         └── config.yaml
├── main.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
```

The config.go file responsible for loading the app's configuration and it should happen automatically on the first time the config package is imported. Therefore, I configured there an init method that will load all the relevant settings and set it:

```
package config
import ( "os" )
    var (
        Propery_x string
        Property_y string
        Property_z string
    )
    func init() {
        LoadSettings()
    }
    
    func LoadSettings(){
        Property_x = os.Getenv("X")
        Property_y = os.Getenv("Y")
        Property_z = os.Getenv("Z")
        
       .....
```

I'm having a problem with setting those environment values in the unit tests before the init method of config.go file is called. I followed some guidelines I found here that recommend doing the following :

```
package config
import (
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)
    func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
        os.Setenv("X", "500")
        m.Run()
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    
    func TestLoadSettings(t *testing.T) {
        assert.Equal(t, "500", Property_x, "values arent equal..")
    }
```

As you can understand, the code still uses the default value and the env variable isn't set before the `init()` of config.go.

Another option that I considered: Lazy Loading. In this way I won't need the init method and the settings will be loaded in the first time someone tries to access the configuration.

Comment: Hey JeyJ - a quick reminder again about running your work through a spelling-checker before posting. Most browsers have one built-in these days, so it really is no extra bother.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `init` functions.

Instead call `config.LoadSettings` on startup in your `main` function. In the tests you can then also define the exact sequence of things.

---

There are also packages that can load configuration files, environment variables or command line parameters using the exact same syntax the `flags` package uses. e.g. [namsral/flags](https://github.com/namsral/flag)

Comment: i want to import the config package into other go modules. I dont want other developers to require to do anything that is related to configuration loading of this part..

Comment: I know. I wanted to do the exact same thing when I started with Go 5.5 years ago.

Comment: so you recommend doing so and letting other developers to handle the import ? What do you think about lazy loading ? in this way I wont need the init method and i can cover it with simple tests

Comment: I'm familiar with other frameworks, I'm using viper to load settings from config file. This example just demonstrates the problem that I'm facing since there is no difference what is the source of the settings, the problem is with testing/init.

Comment: Lazy loading could be a possibility reading the file on the first access to a setting, yes.

Comment: Seems like lazyloading is a better approach here, but using it in every place we need to cofigure globals before use looks like a code smells. Is this is really the best practice in go ? Just letting developers who import the code to handle everything that needed for my package ?

Comment: Globals in general are problematic. I'd try to avoid them in the first place. There are only a few places I personally use globals, e.g. logging/metrics package. I initialize the way an app does logging only once in the main and after all other packages can just log without worrying about global settings for it. And even with that usage, some experts (e.g. [Bill Kennedy](https://github.com/goinggo)) don't agree. They pass in the logger into all other code where it's needed.

Comment: I'm now building the logging / metrics / config packages and as you can see it kinda requires that I'll use globals. I'll post the code that I used to solve this issue with lazy loading. Thank you!

Comment: Does other packages that import your logging package declare a global logger , or they just use the methods of the logger defined in the logging package ?

Comment: Other packages just use the functions of the package that internally log to all loggers in a global list, private to the log package. That list is filled at startup or if never setup in the main has a default logger already. (My log package can log to multiple loggers which some of our applications need.) That list is the only global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like @TehSphinX suggested, I decided to use a dedicate method that will return the configuration and not load it automatically. In other words, I implemented lazy loading :

```
 package settings
    var (
        settings       *Settings
        configLoaded *AtomicBoolean = &AtomicBoolean{sync.Mutex{}, false}
    )
    
    type AtomicBoolean struct {
        mu  sync.Mutex
        val bool
    }
    
    type Settings struct {
        property_x string
        property_y string
        property_z string
    }
    
    func (ab *AtomicBoolean) getValue() bool {
        var val bool = false
        ab.mu.Lock()
        val = ab.val
        ab.mu.Unlock()
        return val
    }
    func (ab *AtomicBoolean) setValue(val bool) {
        ab.mu.Lock()
        ab.val = val
        ab.mu.Unlock()
    }
    
    func GetSettings() *Settings {
       if !settingsgLoaded.getValue(){
           loadSettings()
       }
    
    }
    func loadSettings(){
            Property_x = os.Getenv("X")
            Property_y = os.Getenv("Y")
            Property_z = os.Getenv("Z")
            ...
            settingsLoaded.setValue(true)
            .....
```

Now in my tests I can set the env variables and only after call the GetSettings func :

```
package settings
    func TestLoadSettings(t testing.T){
       os.Setenv("X',"500")
       assert.Equal(GetSettings().property_x,"500")
    }
```